# Form's App Script does not replace fields in template accurately

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I have a simple script to generate a doc and PDF upon form submission. It worked well on simple template (e.g. Only 1 sentence, First name, Last name and Company name).

However, when I use a template that's longer, having many fields, and formatting, the code runs but replace the text randomly.

I have tried to hardcode the fields of forms in ascending order as the doc template. However it still replace the text randomly

Can anybody points out what have I done wrong?

My code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var response = e.response;
  var timestamp = response.getTimestamp();
  var [companyName, country, totalEmployees,totalPctWomenEmployees,numberNationality,name1,position1,emailAdd1,linkedin1,funFact1,name2,position2,emailAdd2,linkedin2,gameStage,gameStory] = response.getItemResponses().map(function(f) {return f.getResponse()});

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXX'); 

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXX')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(companyName + '_one pager', folder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());


  var body = doc.getBody(); 


  body.replaceText('{{Company Name}}', companyName);
  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', name1);
  body.replaceText('{{Position}}', position1);
  body.replaceText('{{Email}}', emailAdd1);
  body.replaceText('{{Linkedin}}', linkedin1);
  body.replaceText('{{Fun Fact}}', funFact1);
  body.replaceText('{{Game Stage}}', gameStage);
  body.replaceText('{{Game Story}}', gameStory);


  doc.saveAndClose(); 


  folder.createFile(doc.getAs("application/pdf"));}
```

My template - 
[image: Template with double curly bracket]

Result - 
[image: Red boxed are wrongly replaced fields - randomized]

Question - Does that mean the array declaration in line 3 was supposed to match the order of my form responses columns?

Comment: If the values for replacing are the correct, each placeholder can be correctly replaced. So how about checking the values of `var [companyName, country, totalEmployees,totalPctWomenEmployees,numberNationality,name1,position1,emailAdd1,linkedin1,funFact1,name2,position2,emailAdd2,linkedin2,gameStage,gameStory] = response.getItemResponses().map(function(f) {return f.getResponse()});`?

Comment: Are you getting an error on the logs? Please provide it. Also, if the form response is empty for some questions type, the item will not be retrieve when using [getItemResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getitemresponses), so i.e if you have a [checkbox type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type) question and it's leave empty it'll cause your variables to not have the correct values beacuse the length of the item responses array will be less that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what have went wrong after so many trials and errors!

The reason is because I declared the array variables randomly without following the order of the form responses columns.

The issue is with the part -

```
var [companyName, country, totalEmployees,totalPctWomenEmployees,numberNationality,name1,position1,emailAdd1,linkedin1,funFact1,name2,position2,emailAdd2,linkedin2,gameStage,gameStory] = response.getItemResponses().map(function(f) {return f.getResponse()});
```

It's actually pulling responses from the spreadsheet, and should be corrected in order. The wrongly mapped values was what causing the replacement of text went haywire. I corrected the order as per form responses and it is all good now.

Learning points: 
If you swapped around the variables, what `response.getItemResponses().map(function(f) {return f.getResponse()}` does is that it will go through the form responses column by column in order, and it will map the content to the wrong variable. As a result, when you replace your text later using `body.replaceText('{{Game Stage}}', gameStage)`, there might be possibility that whatever stored in `gameStage` might be `name1`. Hence the replaced text will be wrong. And you will scratch your head until it bleeds without knowing why.

I saw @Tanaike's comment after I found the answer, but totally spot on!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expresion:

```
body.replace(/{{Company Name}}/g, companyName); // /g replace globaly all value like  {{Company Name}}
```